# k means clustering result storing for later use

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am exploring r programming environment for performing clustering analysis on my test data. For testing I am using a single column data set with the following scatter plot and histogram plotted against the value index.

[image]

[image]
From the data I feel the values can be partitioned into 7 clusters. And when I use `kmeans` function with no of clusters argument as 7, I get the following result.

`Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1]    492.480   2979.013   1903.396  18682.262   1430.533 754221.504
 (between_SS / total_SS =  98.3 %)`

**Now my doubt is how to store this result( not necessarily in r)** so that when I get a new data set ***I should be able to compare the i/p data set with already stored clustering result*** . I should be able to partition the i/p data set values into the already known clusters.

Comment: Why are you trying to "cluster" data that's already in 7 discrete values??

Comment: @SeñorO eight actually ;-) but i agree the example presented is not very really helpful.

Comment: Senor this is a test data set. The real data would be denser.

Comment: if your purpose is to validate the stability of your clustering with kmeans, i suggest the clValid package (see the documentation)

Comment: You could also try the mlr package, see [the tutorial](http://berndbischl.github.io/mlr/tutorial/html/predict/index.html).

Comment: Thanks agenis and Lars!

Answer (score 1):

Examine the **Value** section of `help(kmeans)`. The centers will tell you where the center of the mean is. For incoming data, compute which center it is closest to. Example:

```
data(mtcars)
mt.k <- kmeans(mtcars, centers = 4)
mt.k$centers
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not immediately obvious how to deal with `kmeans` objects. The easiest thing to do is attach it to your dataframe:

```
 k = kmeans(data, centers = 7)
 data = k$cluster
```

Now you have the cluster number as a column in the data.frame. Save however you'd save a data.frame.